# Dynamic height of tableview cell on basis of UICollectionView cell inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have tableview cell inside which i have collectionview and further it has collectionview cell, how can i set height of tableview cell on basis of collectionview cell ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your controller

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague.

You suppose to provide an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Suppose you have static height for collection view cell:
Easy, auto layout will be your friend.
Using:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

However, if you would like to dynamically layout table view cell height:

1. Set height constraint for minimum height of collection view cell
2. Calculate the content size:

```swift
// You may need to call it when viewDidLayoutSubviews() is called
let height = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = height
contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: what i want is to dyanmically set height of collectionview on basis of uicollectionview cell?